# Print NULL Value column Name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with the columns ColA, ... , ColE as below. I need to check each record and show the column name which has NULL value in another existing column called Comments

```
ColA   ColB    ColC    ColD   ColE   Comments
----   ----    -----   ----   ----   ------------------------------
1      7       3       4      NULL   NULL VALUE In ColE      
2      9       NULL    12     NULL   NULL VALUE in ColC, ColE   
3      NULL    NULL    NULL   10     NULL VALUE IN ColB, Colc, ColD
```

The Output should be similar to the `Comments` column from the above result set.

Comment: What is more important to you: simplicity of code (ease of maintenance), or efficiency (speed of execution)? Don't say **both**! There are ways to solve this that are efficient, but the code is more cumbersome.

Comment: Please clarify: What do you mean by **existing** column called Comments? Does your table (saved on disk) have such a column? Or do you just need that column in the output of a `SELECT` query? (As opposed to: the column does exist, and you need to `UPDATE` it and save the result on disk.)

Comment: I have a created a column called Comments - if any row having null and that column name should be updated in Comments columns as - NULL Value in ColE.... if more column then it should all those collumn

Comment: More on simplicity of code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using only plain SQL (no procedures or functions etc.), for example with a `MERGE` statement. A complete session, starting with setting up the table, inserting values, adding one more column for comments, then the `MERGE` statement, and the results "before" and "after" are shown below.

I added one more row of data, where there are no `NULL` values. You always need something like this to test the solution: does it work correctly when there are **no** `NULL` values in a row?

The real work is done in the subquery labeled `x` in the solution below. First I `unpivot` the data from the original table (adding the `ROWID` so I can identify each row later). `UNPIVOT` requires Oracle 11.1 or higher; I also use `LISTAGG` which requires Oracle 11.2 or higher. You tagged your post with both `oracle11g` and `oracle10g` so I don't really know what you have, and in any case `11g` and such are marketing names; the proper version is 11.1 or 11.2 (or, really, 11.2.0.4.0 and similar). You can find out your version with `select * from v$version`.

If you don't have Oracle 11.2, the string aggregation can be done with other tools (hierarchical query, or `XMLAGG`, etc.) - Stack Overflow is full of questions about how that is done. Similarly, if you don't have Oracle 11.1, unpivoting can be done with a cross join; I didn't check, but I assume there are lots of questions about that on Stack Overflow also. Both operations are standard, and unrelated to your question; if you need help, start by searching this site, and write back if you run into difficulties.

So, back to my approach. I unpivot the data, keeping track of `rowid`. In the `unpivot` operation I include nulls (which is not the default, so `include nulls` is needed). Then from the result I keep only the rows where the value is `NULL`. Then I group by `RID` and aggregate with `LISTAGG`. This prepares the subquery `x` for the `MERGE` operation, which is standard beyond this point.

**Note about efficiency** I asked the OP in a comment whether fast execution or simplicity of the solution (easier maintenance) should be preferred. The OP said easy maintenance is more important. The solution below is clearer, but it is not efficient for the following reason. In the original table the values in the five columns are already "grouped" by the fact they appear in the same row. Unpivoting loses this information; then we must group by `ROWID` again, to create the `LISTAGG` strings and to prepare for `MERGE`. The `GROUP BY` operation is expensive, and it wouldn't be needed if we wrote code that didn't break up the input rows. But writing a solution that doesn't break up the input rows, while possible, is messier, especially as the number of columns increases.

**SETUP**

```
create table tbl(cola number, colb number, colc number, cold number,cole number);
insert into tbl(cola, colb, colc, cold, cole) values (1,    7,    3,    4, NULL);  
insert into tbl(cola, colb, colc, cold, cole) values (2,    9, NULL,   12, NULL);
insert into tbl(cola, colb, colc, cold, cole) values (3, NULL, NULL, NULL,   10);
insert into tbl(cola, colb, colc, cold, cole) values (0,    1,    2,    3,    5);
commit;

alter table tbl add (comment_about_nulls varchar2(1000));

select * from tbl;

COLA COLB COLC COLD COLE COMMENT_ABOUT_NULLS                    
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----------------------------------------
   1    7    3    4                                              
   2    9        12                                              
   3                  10
   0    1    2    3    4
```

**SOLUTION**

```
merge into tbl
using (
        select   rid, listagg(colname, ', ') within group (order by colname) str
        from     (select rowid as rid, cola, colb, colc, cold, cole from tbl)
        unpivot  include nulls (val for colname in 
                          (cola as 'ColA', colb as 'ColB', colc as 'ColC',
                                           cold as 'ColD', cole as 'ColE'))
        where    val is null
        group by rid
      ) x
  on (tbl.rowid = x.rid)
when matched then update
  set tbl.comment_about_nulls = 'NULL VALUE IN ' || x.str
;

select * from tbl;

COLA COLB COLC COLD COLE COMMENT_ABOUT_NULLS                    
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----------------------------------------
   1    7    3    4      NULL VALUE IN ColE                      
   2    9        12      NULL VALUE IN ColC, ColE                
   3                  10 NULL VALUE IN ColB, ColC, ColD          
   0    1    2    3    5
```

Comment: thank you my collegue(mathematician), i admired your solution.

Comment: @mathguy - Thanks much, it worked as per my requirements. Appreciate your time and help

Answer (score 0):

is that the code you want?

```
declare 
  v_table_name  varchar2(31)  := 'MYTABLE';
  v_sql         varchar2(4000);
  v_columnName  varchar2(100);
  v_col         pls_integer; 
  cm            varchar2(1); 
  i             pls_integer := 0;   
begin
for b in ( select rownum rnum, t.rowid rid, t.* from mytable t order by rownum )
loop
 begin
 for c in ( select t.* from user_tab_columns t where t.table_name = v_table_name order by column_name ) 
 loop    
   v_sql := 'select ' || c.column_name  || ' from ' || v_table_name || ' t where t.rowid = '''||b.rid||'''';
   execute immediate v_sql into v_col; 
   if nvl(v_col,0)=0 then     
     if i>0 then cm:=','; end if;
     v_columnName := v_columnName||cm||c.column_name; 
     i:=+1;
   end if; 
 end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad(nvl(to_char(b.rnum),'NULL'),5,' ')||' '||rpad(nvl(to_char(b.cola),'NULL'),5,' ')||' '||rpad(nvl(to_char(b.colb),'NULL'),5,' ')||' '||rpad(nvl(to_char(b.colc),'NULL'),5,' ')||' '||rpad(nvl(to_char(b.cold),'NULL'),5,' ')||' '||rpad(nvl(to_char(b.cole),'NULL'),5,' ')||' '||'NULL VALUE In '||v_columnName); 
    v_columnName := null; i := 0; cm := null;
  exception when no_data_found then continue;
 end; 
end loop; 
end;
```

by considering colA - E as number type and comments is non-existent in mytable.

Comment: ColA   ColB    ColC    ColD   ColE  
----   ----    -----   ----   ----  
1      7       3       4      NULL 
2      9       NULL    12     NULL     
3      NULL    NULL    NULL   10 


My Result should look like this, please not column contains both number and Varchar values

Result

NULL VALUE In ColE
NULL VALUE in ColC, ColE
NULL VALUE IN ColB, Colc, ColD

Comment: Thanks for the response. below is what the output I am expecting

ColA   ColB    ColC    ColD   ColE  
----   ----    -----   ----   ----  
1      7       3       4      NULL 
2      9       NULL    12     NULL     
3      NULL    NULL    NULL   10 


My Result should look like this, please not column contains both number and Varchar values

Result

NULL VALUE In ColE
NULL VALUE in ColC, ColE
NULL VALUE IN ColB, Colc, ColD

Comment: part " ...'NULL VALUE In '||v_columnName" already stands for this ( comments ). Have you tried the code, really? Only, i didn't put any code for the title part.

Comment: This is how I am getting the output. Please note I am still a newbie for SQL

1     1     7     3     4     NULL  NULL VALUE In 
2     2     9     NULL  12    NULL  NULL VALUE In 
3     3     NULL  NULL  NULL  10    NULL VALUE In

Comment: Need one more small help, How do I update the output to My_table respective records result column.

Comment: There is no need for procedures in this problem. They say "row by row is slow by slow" (meaning, if you update one row at a time, in a loop, the execution will be **much** slower). For the same reason, they say "don't do in PL/SQL what can be done in plain SQL". This problem can be solved in several ways in plain SQL.